# How can I make sure Jython doesn't retain "sensitive" comments in compiled $py.class files?

Tags: java, python, jython

I wanted to see whether comments or strings get retained in $py.class files, so I tried an experiment with Jython 2.5.3 and Jython 2.7.0. (In my case, the original .py files are not made public, but the $py.class files are part of a .jar which is published; I don't want certain comments to be visible)

```
C:\tmp\jython>java -jar c:\app\java\lib\jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar
Jython 2.7.0 (default:9987c746f838, Apr 29 2015, 02:25:11)
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Oracle Corporation)] on java1.8.0_152
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import py_compile
>>> py_compile.compile('loose_lips.py')
```

where loose_lips.py contains:

```
def loose_lips_sink_ships(x):
    """CM1 Doc comment"""

    # CM2 line comment

    """ 
    CM3 Another multiline string that doesn't do anything
    but is not a doc comment
    """

    return x+1

    """
    CM4 Yet another comment that could theoretically
    be optimized out, since we can never get here
    """
```

I predicted that CM1 would be the only string content retained in the resulting output, because it has well-defined semantics in Python --- it's the docstring, so it gets stuffed into `loose_lips.loose_lips_sink_ships.__doc__`. There's no reason for the rest to end up in any runtime code.

If I run `py_compile.compile('loose_lips.py')` in Python 2.7.14 (or just `import loose_lips`) then it generates a .pyc file containing bytecode and the only retained text is CM1, as predicted.

If I run `py_compile.compile('loose_lips.py')` in Jython 2.5.3 or Jython 2.7.0, then the resulting $py.class file contains CM1 and CM3.

**Why does CM3 get retained at runtime?** Is there any externally-visible behavior that the Jython interpreter is trying to ensure (e.g. retaining source code?) that requires this retention of multiline strings? Is there any way I can prevent it?

I decompiled the $py.class file on http://www.javadecompilers.com and here are the results:

```
import org.python.core.PyRunnableBootstrap;
import org.python.core.CodeBootstrap;
import org.python.core.CodeLoader;
import org.python.core.PyFunction;
import org.python.core.PyString;
import org.python.core.Py;
import org.python.core.PyObject;
import org.python.core.ThreadState;
import org.python.core.PyFrame;
import org.python.core.PyCode;
import org.python.compiler.Filename;
import org.python.compiler.MTime;
import org.python.compiler.APIVersion;
import org.python.core.PyRunnable;
import org.python.core.PyFunctionTable;

// 
// Decompiled by Procyon v0.5.36
// 

@APIVersion(36)
@MTime(1578883953709L)
@Filename("loose_lips.py")
public class loose_lips$py extends PyFunctionTable implements PyRunnable
{
    static loose_lips$py self;
    static final PyCode f$0;
    static final PyCode loose_lips_sink_ships$1;

    public PyObject f$0(final PyFrame pyFrame, final ThreadState threadState) {
        pyFrame.setline(1);
        pyFrame.setlocal("loose_lips_sink_ships", (PyObject)new PyFunction(pyFrame.f_globals, Py.EmptyObjects, loose_lips$py.loose_lips_sink_ships$1, (PyObject)PyString.fromInterned("CM1 Doc comment")));
        pyFrame.f_lasti = -1;
        return Py.None;
    }

    public PyObject loose_lips_sink_ships$1(final PyFrame pyFrame, final ThreadState threadState) {
        pyFrame.setline(2);
        PyString.fromInterned("CM1 Doc comment");
        pyFrame.setline(9);
        PyString.fromInterned(" \n    CM3 Another multiline string that doesn't do anything\n    but is not a doc comment\n    ");
        pyFrame.setline(11);
        final PyObject add = pyFrame.getlocal(0)._add((PyObject)Py.newInteger(1));
        pyFrame.f_lasti = -1;
        return add;
    }

    public loose_lips$py(final String s) {
        loose_lips$py.self = this;
        f$0 = Py.newCode(0, new String[0], s, "<module>", 0, false, false, (PyFunctionTable)loose_lips$py.self, 0, (String[])null, (String[])null, 0, 4096);
        loose_lips_sink_ships$1 = Py.newCode(1, new String[] { "x" }, s, "loose_lips_sink_ships", 1, false, false, (PyFunctionTable)loose_lips$py.self, 1, (String[])null, (String[])null, 0, 4097);
    }

    public PyCode getMain() {
        return loose_lips$py.f$0;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] array) {
        Py.runMain(CodeLoader.createSimpleBootstrap(new loose_lips$py("loose_lips$py").getMain()), array);
    }

    public static CodeBootstrap getCodeBootstrap() {
        return PyRunnableBootstrap.getFilenameConstructorReflectionBootstrap((Class)loose_lips$py.class);
    }

    public PyObject call_function(final int n, final PyFrame pyFrame, final ThreadState threadState) {
        switch (n) {
            case 0: {
                return this.f$0(pyFrame, threadState);
            }
            case 1: {
                return this.loose_lips_sink_ships$1(pyFrame, threadState);
            }
            default: {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because Jython doesn't eliminate dead code, relying on the JVM's JIT compiler to do that, perhaps?

Comment: See [What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170415/144918) -- note the guidance is that SO is only for *practical*, answerable questions about problems you face. Knowing the answer to this doesn't let you fix any bug, or change how you go about the *practice* of programming with Jython (and half the time, the real answer to a question about why feature X hasn't been written will be about implementors' priorities, timelines, competing bugs/work items, etc; and aren't really knowable to anyone else).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I completely disagree. This question is about language implementation behavior. Very few systems are completely usable as a black box; understanding what goes on inside can help you be a better programmer. In my case, the application for knowing how this works is that I have comments in my code that I do not want to be visible by customers that have access to the compiled .py files. So knowing whether they are retained is important. I will change the title.

Comment: Also, the behavior of docstrings is "magic" and not obvious to beginner Python programmers; I wanted to know if there are any other externally-visible effects of including multiline strings which may cause them to be retained.

Comment: @Andreas Comments are not code of any kind, let alone dead code. These ones have been compiled as string literals.

Comment: @user207421 Of course they have been compiled as string literals, since `"""` is a *multi-line string literal*, not a comment.

Comment: @user207421, ...to reinforce the differentiation from comments -- docstrings are metadata of the object to which they're attached, interactively queryable at runtime.

Comment: I agree -- much better title, now asks a practical and answerable question; close vote isn't mine, or I'd have reversed it.